# how to get list of Destination Log Groups to show up in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-permissions

I am trying to create my first flow log monitoring in cloudwatch.. but noticing that the log group I've made is not showing up at all

notice :

[image]

But when I am attempting to use this group ______ in the creation of the flow log.. the dropdown is empty and I've already enabled all the `Describe*` `Get*` that I can think of under CloudWatch in AWS Organizations for myself

[image]

Comment: Are they in the same AWS region?

Comment: @jellycsc no they were not! okay I think you deserve a point.. please post that and will mark it.. meanwhile I am deleting the ones in virginia and starting over , thanks for the simple reminder

Comment: Absolutely. Hope it helps others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha, this happens to me several times. Please make sure they are in the same region :)